# The four digit number $AABB$ can be divided by $6$ without remainder. Determine the greatest and least value of $AABB$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> The four digit number $AABB$ can be divided by $6$ without remainder. Determine the greatest and least value of $AABB$.

On the condition that a number can be divided by $6$, it must be divisible by both $2$ and $3$

$$AABB \equiv 0 \pmod{2}\tag{1}$$
$$AABB \equiv 0 \pmod{3}\tag{2}$$

Reducing $AABB \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$,

$$AABB \equiv 0 \pmod{2} \implies 1000A + 100A + 10B + B \implies B \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$$

Now reducing $AABB \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$,

$$AABB \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \implies 1000A + 100A +10B + B \implies A + A + B + B \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \implies 2(A+B) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$

I think I've gone wrong so far.

Comment: Should it be $B \equiv 0 \pmod 2$?

Comment: @xbh Yes, it should. Sorry for that mistake. See the new edit.

Comment: $AABB=11\times A0B$.

Comment: It should be $2(A+B)\equiv0\pmod{3}$  You have $B\equiv0\pmod2$  That does not say that $\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: @saulspatz How?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"?

Comment: @saulspatz I didn't get what you exactly mean by that.

Comment: You had a mistake in your formula.  I pointed it out and you corrected it.  You seem to have understood what I said.  I really can't figure out what you are asking.  What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @saulspatz By such means, no clue about how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that we must have $B$ even and $A+B$ divisible by $3$.  To make $AABB$ as large as possible, we'd like to have $A=9$  If this is so, can we find an even number $B$ such that $3|(9+B)?$ Similarly, to make $AABB$ as small as possible, we'd like to have $A=1$.  What are the choices for $B?$

Comment: Isnt it $3|2(9+B)$, which implies that $3|18+2B$?

Comment: To the proposer: If $n\in \Bbb Z$ then $3|2n \iff 3|n.$ And $3|(9+B)\iff 3|B.$ So $3|2(9+b)\iff 3|(9+B)\iff 3|B.$ So if $A=9$  then $B\in \{0,3,6,9\}.$ But in this Q,  $B$ must also be even. So if $A=9$  then $B\in \{0,3,6,9\}\cap \{0,2,4,6,8\}=\{0,6\}.$

Comment: @Busi If $3|2n$ then $3|n$.  If $p$ is prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$.  Since $3\nmid2$ it must be that $3|n$.